# WCF Service not returning results while stored procedure does. How can I debug?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have implemented a WCF service (written in C#) that serves as a backend to a Webapp. The WCF is supposed to call stored procedures from a SQL database and return the data via JSON so it can be displayed in the WebApp. My issue is that the WCF service sometimes will return an empty JSON array. If I use the same parameters and execute the stored procedure using SQL Management Studio I get hundreds of rows returned. How can I debug this issue? I've been looking at Chrome's dev tools and Firebug and they both show that the request is being responded too (it's just empty).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like your service is a black box that doesn't do any logging? Enable WCF tracing then, or run it with a debugger attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three main places you can debug:

1. Use the WCF test client to call the service directly rather than from front-end code.
2. Use SQL Server profiler to make sure your service is calling the sprocs with the parameters you expect.
3. Attach the debugger to your WCF service and step through the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the WCF Test Client doesn't seem to do anything since I'm using a JSON/REST service. I'll try attaching a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a debugger to the WCF service and see what happens to the result set provided by the DB.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more. I'm a completely green when it comes to this.